# Perform a Google text search with C Sharp or PHP?

Tags: c#, php

Going to [Google code](http://code.google.com/) page I couldn't find the API I should use to perform a basic web search. All other resources I found point to [Google Base API](http://code.google.com/apis/base/) but it is no longer available.

What I need is to be able to sumbit a query string and get back a list with site names. For example, I need to find the first results when searching for "champions league" as if typing the query on the Google page.

What is the correct API to use for text searches these days? Are there any librariries for PHP or C Sharp?

**EDIT**: I found PHP code on the Net that sends requests to ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web. I checked it out and it actually returns search results :) Do you know where I can find info for this endpoint and from what API is it part? Also, [Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/) as suggested by @Rickard doesn't seem to provide this basic functionality. I tried to use it but it asks me to enter the sites I want to search in. I don't want to search particular sites but all.

Thank you

Comment: I had integrated google search in my website. but how can I explain you? Give me your exact requirement!!!!!

Comment: I don't need anything special. Just a way to perform a text search with Google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html)

Comment: Can I query it for "Paris Hilton" and get the same results as if typing the the key term on the Google website? Thanks.

Comment: the same results as an anonymous user, yes. There are numerous sources that can influence the SERP when you're say, logged in as a Google user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I started to read about the Custom Search API and saw that I have to specify the sites to search for. My goal is to perform a regular web text search. Also some PHP code I found on the Net sends requests to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web. I checked it out and it actually returns search results :) Do you know where I can find info for this endpoint and from what API is it part? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work just fine, as the Google API is great unless you need to search +100 times per day, then they charge you. This is a simple solution to this problem, but only works for string searches and not image searches.

Search for "turtle":

```
string searchString = "Turtle";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.google.com/search?q=" + searchString);
```